# Create a sequence numbering in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Good Day. I'm a beginner in XSLT. I have requirement to generate sequence number for every row written into the text file.

I have 2 inner for-Loops and one outer for-loop. For each specific condition of the outer for-loop control passes to the inner 2 for-loops. First inner for-loop writes a couple of rows to the text file followed by second inner for-loop.

Say for instance first inner for-loop writes 3 rows into the text file and then second inner writes 2 rows to the text file, then output should be like

```
SeqNo:
1      
2
3
4
5
```

Below is my XML:

```
<Envelope>
    <Body>
        <Get_Compensation_Eligibility_Rules_Response version="v23.2">
            <Request_References>
                <Compensation_Eligibility_Rule_Reference Descriptor="AAFT Workday Management">
                    <ID type="WID">1a90d104082a101c6a5b8adb783c0891</ID>
                    <ID type="Condition_Rule_ID">CONDITION_RULE-6-999</ID>
                </Compensation_Eligibility_Rule_Reference>
            </Request_References>
            <Response_Filter>
                <As_Of_Effective_Date>2015-08-04-07:00</As_Of_Effective_Date>
                <As_Of_Entry_DateTime>2015-08-04T23:51:56.000-07:00</As_Of_Entry_DateTime>
                <Page>1</Page>
                <Count>100</Count>
            </Response_Filter>
            <Response_Results>
                <Total_Results>1</Total_Results>
                <Total_Pages>1</Total_Pages>
                <Page_Results>1</Page_Results>
                <Page>1</Page>
            </Response_Results>
            <Response_Data>
                <Compensation_Eligibility_Rule>
                    <Compensation_Eligibility_Rule_Data>
                        <Effective_Date>2015-08-04-07:00</Effective_Date>
                        <Rule_Data>
                            <Condition_Rule_ID>CONDITION_RULE-6-999</Condition_Rule_ID>
                            <Rule_Description>AAFT Workday Management</Rule_Description>
                            <Condition_Item_Data>
                                <Order>a</Order>
                                <And_Or_Operator_Reference Descriptor="And">
                                    <ID type="WID">da4e1c34446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</ID>
                                    <ID type="And_Or_Operator_Name">And</ID>
                                </And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                                <Relational_Operator_Reference
                                    Descriptor="any in the selection list">
                                    <ID type="WID">d5227566446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</ID>
                                    <ID type="Relational_Operator_Name">any in the selection
                                        list</ID>
                                </Relational_Operator_Reference>
                                <Condition_Entry_Option_Reference
                                    Descriptor="Value specified in this filter">
                                    <ID type="WID">da59516c446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</ID>
                                    <ID type="Condition_Entry_Option_Name">Value specified in
                                        this filter</ID>
                                </Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                                <Source_External_Field_Reference
                                    Descriptor="Organization and Superior Organizations (Compensation)">
                                    <ID type="WID">a82f9b81a414453cbf2b103af7d1484f</ID>
                                </Source_External_Field_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference
                                    Descriptor="AAFT Workday (David Harris)">
                                    <ID type="WID">1a90d104082a101c6485a8ac1a3c0750</ID>
                                    <ID type="Organization_Reference_ID"
                                        >SUPERVISORY_ORGANIZATION-6-327</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                            </Condition_Item_Data>
                            <Condition_Item_Data>
                                <Order>b</Order>
                                <And_Or_Operator_Reference Descriptor="And">
                                    <ID type="WID">da4e1c34446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</ID>
                                    <ID type="And_Or_Operator_Name">And</ID>
                                </And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                                <Relational_Operator_Reference
                                    Descriptor="in the selection list">
                                    <ID type="WID">d5228d9e446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</ID>
                                    <ID type="Relational_Operator_Name">in the selection
                                        list</ID>
                                </Relational_Operator_Reference>
                                <Condition_Entry_Option_Reference
                                    Descriptor="Value specified in this filter">
                                    <ID type="WID">da59516c446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</ID>
                                    <ID type="Condition_Entry_Option_Name">Value specified in
                                        this filter</ID>
                                </Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                                <Source_External_Field_Reference
                                    Descriptor="Management Level (Compensation)">
                                    <ID type="WID">6c04adc731e645309d41fb9b9dc5de45</ID>
                                </Source_External_Field_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference Descriptor="6 Manager">
                                    <ID type="WID">0e93fa4e0cc94867adb662a0ee8430d5</ID>
                                    <ID type="Management_Level_ID">6_Manager</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference Descriptor="5 Director">
                                    <ID type="WID">0b778018b3b44ca3959e498041865645</ID>
                                    <ID type="Management_Level_ID">5_Director</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference Descriptor="4 Vice President">
                                    <ID type="WID">679d4d1ac6da40e19deb7d91e170431d</ID>
                                    <ID type="Management_Level_ID">4_Vice_President</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference
                                    Descriptor="3 Executive Vice President">
                                    <ID type="WID">0ceb3292987b474bbc40c751a1e22c69</ID>
                                    <ID type="Management_Level_ID"
                                        >3_Executive_Vice_President</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference
                                    Descriptor="2 Chief Executive Officer">
                                    <ID type="WID">3de1f2834f064394a40a40a727fb6c6d</ID>
                                    <ID type="Management_Level_ID"
                                        >2_Chief_Executive_Officer</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference Descriptor="1 Board of Directors">
                                    <ID type="WID">438baab049b14657b7d52ddb4703cc3e</ID>
                                    <ID type="Management_Level_ID">1_Board_of_Directors</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                            </Condition_Item_Data>
                        </Rule_Data>
                        <Compensation_Grade_Reference
                            Descriptor="AAFT Workday Management  Grade">
                            <ID type="WID">1a90d104082a101c6ad761aaeb2408ad</ID>
                            <ID type="Compensation_Grade_ID">COMPENSATION_GRADE-6-19</ID>
                        </Compensation_Grade_Reference>
                        <Compensation_Plan_Reference
                            Descriptor="AAFT Workday Car Allowance Plan">
                            <ID type="WID">1a90d104082a101c6b7f66f03dfc08e8</ID>
                            <ID type="Compensation_Plan_ID">ALLOWANCE_AMOUNT_PLAN-6-14</ID>
                        </Compensation_Plan_Reference>
                        <Compensation_Plan_Reference Descriptor="AAFT Merit Plan">
                            <ID type="WID">c49a621d552b102865843b4496fc91c7</ID>
                            <ID type="Compensation_Plan_ID">MERIT_PLAN-6-37</ID>
                        </Compensation_Plan_Reference>
                    </Compensation_Eligibility_Rule_Data>
                </Compensation_Eligibility_Rule>
            </Response_Data>
        </Get_Compensation_Eligibility_Rules_Response>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

My XSLT is Below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Report_Data_Outer">

        <xsl:text>Eligibility Rule</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Reference ID</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>And Or Operator</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Relational Operator</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Entry_Option</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Source_External_Field</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Source_Condition_Rule</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Target_Instance</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Boolean</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/Body/Get_Compensation_Eligibility_Rules_Response/Response_Data/Compensation_Eligibility_Rule/Compensation_Eligibility_Rule_Data/Rule_Data">


            <xsl:variable name="Rule_Description"><xsl:value-of select="(Rule_Description)"/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="Condition_Rule_ID"><xsl:value-of select="(Condition_Rule_ID)"/></xsl:variable>

            <xsl:for-each select="Condition_Item_Data">
                <xsl:variable name="And_Or_Operator"><xsl:value-of select="(And_Or_Operator_Reference/ID[2])"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="Relational_Operator"><xsl:value-of select="(Relational_Operator_Reference/ID[2])"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="Condition_Entry_Option"><xsl:value-of select="(Condition_Entry_Option_Reference/ID[2])"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="Source_External_Field"><xsl:value-of select="(Source_External_Field_Reference[1]/@Descriptor)"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="Source_Condition_Rule"><xsl:value-of select="(Source_Condition_Rule_Reference[1]/@Descriptor)"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="Boolean"><xsl:value-of select="(Filter_Boolean)"/></xsl:variable>

                <xsl:for-each select="Target_Instance_Reference">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Rule_Description"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Condition_Rule_ID"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$And_Or_Operator"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Relational_Operator"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Condition_Entry_Option"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Source_External_Field"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Source_Condition_Rule"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Descriptor"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>

                </xsl:for-each>

                <xsl:for-each select="Filter_Boolean">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Rule_Description"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Condition_Rule_ID"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$And_Or_Operator"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Relational_Operator"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Condition_Entry_Option"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Source_External_Field"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Source_Condition_Rule"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Boolean"/>  
                    <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The inner loops are based on `for-each select="Target_Instance_Reference"` and `for-each select="Filter_Boolean"`. I tried using position function but it generates rows like below:

sequence numbers generated: 1,1,2,3,4,5,6

But it to be like below (expected):

sequence numbers expected: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Requesting gurus , please suggest me how do I get my SeqNo generation corrected.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your examples don't seem to work with copy/paste and I don't have time to figure out why right now, but after taking a quick look at your stylesheet I think you should try replacing:

```
<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:number level="any" count="Target_Instance_Reference|Filter_Boolean"/>
```

in both of your inner loops (`xsl:for-each`'s that select `Target_Instance_Reference` and `Filter_Boolean` if I understand correctly).

Here's a slightly modified version of your XSLT that produces the sequence numbers that you requested. However, `Filter_Boolean` does not exist in the XML input so if you're still getting incorrect sequence numbers, you will need to update your question with a better input example.

**XML Input**

```
<Envelope>
    <Body>
        <Get_Compensation_Eligibility_Rules_Response version="v23.2">
            <Request_References>
                <Compensation_Eligibility_Rule_Reference Descriptor="AAFT Workday Management">
                    <ID type="WID">1a90d104082a101c6a5b8adb783c0891</ID>
                    <ID type="Condition_Rule_ID">CONDITION_RULE-6-999</ID>
                </Compensation_Eligibility_Rule_Reference>
            </Request_References>
            <Response_Filter>
                <As_Of_Effective_Date>2015-08-04-07:00</As_Of_Effective_Date>
                <As_Of_Entry_DateTime>2015-08-04T23:51:56.000-07:00</As_Of_Entry_DateTime>
                <Page>1</Page>
                <Count>100</Count>
            </Response_Filter>
            <Response_Results>
                <Total_Results>1</Total_Results>
                <Total_Pages>1</Total_Pages>
                <Page_Results>1</Page_Results>
                <Page>1</Page>
            </Response_Results>
            <Response_Data>
                <Compensation_Eligibility_Rule>
                    <Compensation_Eligibility_Rule_Data>
                        <Effective_Date>2015-08-04-07:00</Effective_Date>
                        <Rule_Data>
                            <Condition_Rule_ID>CONDITION_RULE-6-999</Condition_Rule_ID>
                            <Rule_Description>AAFT Workday Management</Rule_Description>
                            <Condition_Item_Data>
                                <Order>a</Order>
                                <And_Or_Operator_Reference Descriptor="And">
                                    <ID type="WID">da4e1c34446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</ID>
                                    <ID type="And_Or_Operator_Name">And</ID>
                                </And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                                <Relational_Operator_Reference
                                    Descriptor="any in the selection list">
                                    <ID type="WID">d5227566446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</ID>
                                    <ID type="Relational_Operator_Name">any in the selection
                                        list</ID>
                                </Relational_Operator_Reference>
                                <Condition_Entry_Option_Reference
                                    Descriptor="Value specified in this filter">
                                    <ID type="WID">da59516c446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</ID>
                                    <ID type="Condition_Entry_Option_Name">Value specified in
                                        this filter</ID>
                                </Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                                <Source_External_Field_Reference
                                    Descriptor="Organization and Superior Organizations (Compensation)">
                                    <ID type="WID">a82f9b81a414453cbf2b103af7d1484f</ID>
                                </Source_External_Field_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference
                                    Descriptor="AAFT Workday (David Harris)">
                                    <ID type="WID">1a90d104082a101c6485a8ac1a3c0750</ID>
                                    <ID type="Organization_Reference_ID"
                                        >SUPERVISORY_ORGANIZATION-6-327</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                            </Condition_Item_Data>
                            <Condition_Item_Data>
                                <Order>b</Order>
                                <And_Or_Operator_Reference Descriptor="And">
                                    <ID type="WID">da4e1c34446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</ID>
                                    <ID type="And_Or_Operator_Name">And</ID>
                                </And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                                <Relational_Operator_Reference
                                    Descriptor="in the selection list">
                                    <ID type="WID">d5228d9e446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</ID>
                                    <ID type="Relational_Operator_Name">in the selection
                                        list</ID>
                                </Relational_Operator_Reference>
                                <Condition_Entry_Option_Reference
                                    Descriptor="Value specified in this filter">
                                    <ID type="WID">da59516c446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</ID>
                                    <ID type="Condition_Entry_Option_Name">Value specified in
                                        this filter</ID>
                                </Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                                <Source_External_Field_Reference
                                    Descriptor="Management Level (Compensation)">
                                    <ID type="WID">6c04adc731e645309d41fb9b9dc5de45</ID>
                                </Source_External_Field_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference Descriptor="6 Manager">
                                    <ID type="WID">0e93fa4e0cc94867adb662a0ee8430d5</ID>
                                    <ID type="Management_Level_ID">6_Manager</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference Descriptor="5 Director">
                                    <ID type="WID">0b778018b3b44ca3959e498041865645</ID>
                                    <ID type="Management_Level_ID">5_Director</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference Descriptor="4 Vice President">
                                    <ID type="WID">679d4d1ac6da40e19deb7d91e170431d</ID>
                                    <ID type="Management_Level_ID">4_Vice_President</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference
                                    Descriptor="3 Executive Vice President">
                                    <ID type="WID">0ceb3292987b474bbc40c751a1e22c69</ID>
                                    <ID type="Management_Level_ID"
                                        >3_Executive_Vice_President</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference
                                    Descriptor="2 Chief Executive Officer">
                                    <ID type="WID">3de1f2834f064394a40a40a727fb6c6d</ID>
                                    <ID type="Management_Level_ID"
                                        >2_Chief_Executive_Officer</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                                <Target_Instance_Reference Descriptor="1 Board of Directors">
                                    <ID type="WID">438baab049b14657b7d52ddb4703cc3e</ID>
                                    <ID type="Management_Level_ID">1_Board_of_Directors</ID>
                                </Target_Instance_Reference>
                            </Condition_Item_Data>
                        </Rule_Data>
                        <Compensation_Grade_Reference
                            Descriptor="AAFT Workday Management  Grade">
                            <ID type="WID">1a90d104082a101c6ad761aaeb2408ad</ID>
                            <ID type="Compensation_Grade_ID">COMPENSATION_GRADE-6-19</ID>
                        </Compensation_Grade_Reference>
                        <Compensation_Plan_Reference
                            Descriptor="AAFT Workday Car Allowance Plan">
                            <ID type="WID">1a90d104082a101c6b7f66f03dfc08e8</ID>
                            <ID type="Compensation_Plan_ID">ALLOWANCE_AMOUNT_PLAN-6-14</ID>
                        </Compensation_Plan_Reference>
                        <Compensation_Plan_Reference Descriptor="AAFT Merit Plan">
                            <ID type="WID">c49a621d552b102865843b4496fc91c7</ID>
                            <ID type="Compensation_Plan_ID">MERIT_PLAN-6-37</ID>
                        </Compensation_Plan_Reference>
                    </Compensation_Eligibility_Rule_Data>
                </Compensation_Eligibility_Rule>
            </Response_Data>
        </Get_Compensation_Eligibility_Rules_Response>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"></xsl:output>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:text>Eligibility Rule</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Reference ID</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>And Or Operator</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Relational Operator</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Entry_Option</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Source_External_Field</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Source_Condition_Rule</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Target_Instance</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Boolean</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:for-each select="Envelope/Body/Get_Compensation_Eligibility_Rules_Response/Response_Data/Compensation_Eligibility_Rule/Compensation_Eligibility_Rule_Data/Rule_Data">
            <xsl:variable name="Rule_Description"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Rule_Description)"/></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="Condition_Rule_ID"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Condition_Rule_ID)"/></xsl:variable>

            <xsl:for-each select="Condition_Item_Data">
                <xsl:variable name="And_Or_Operator"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(And_Or_Operator_Reference/ID[2])"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="Relational_Operator"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Relational_Operator_Reference/ID[2])"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="Condition_Entry_Option"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Condition_Entry_Option_Reference/ID[2])"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="Source_External_Field"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Source_External_Field_Reference[1]/@Descriptor)"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="Source_Condition_Rule"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Source_Condition_Rule_Reference[1]/@Descriptor)"/></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="Boolean"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Filter_Boolean)"/></xsl:variable>

                <xsl:for-each select="Target_Instance_Reference">
                    <xsl:number level="any" count="Target_Instance_Reference|Filter_Boolean"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Rule_Description"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Condition_Rule_ID"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$And_Or_Operator"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Relational_Operator"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Condition_Entry_Option"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Source_External_Field"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Source_Condition_Rule"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Descriptor"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>

                </xsl:for-each>

                <xsl:for-each select="Filter_Boolean">
                    <xsl:number level="any" count="Target_Instance_Reference|Filter_Boolean"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Rule_Description"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Condition_Rule_ID"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$And_Or_Operator"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Relational_Operator"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Condition_Entry_Option"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Source_External_Field"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Source_Condition_Rule"/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Boolean"/>  
                    <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
Eligibility Rule,Reference ID,And Or Operator,Relational Operator,Entry_Option,Source_External_Field,Source_Condition_Rule,Target_Instance,Boolean
1,AAFT Workday Management,CONDITION_RULE-6-999,And,any in the selection list,Value specified in this filter,Organization and Superior Organizations (Compensation),,AAFT Workday (David Harris)
2,AAFT Workday Management,CONDITION_RULE-6-999,And,in the selection list,Value specified in this filter,Management Level (Compensation),,6 Manager
3,AAFT Workday Management,CONDITION_RULE-6-999,And,in the selection list,Value specified in this filter,Management Level (Compensation),,5 Director
4,AAFT Workday Management,CONDITION_RULE-6-999,And,in the selection list,Value specified in this filter,Management Level (Compensation),,4 Vice President
5,AAFT Workday Management,CONDITION_RULE-6-999,And,in the selection list,Value specified in this filter,Management Level (Compensation),,3 Executive Vice President
6,AAFT Workday Management,CONDITION_RULE-6-999,And,in the selection list,Value specified in this filter,Management Level (Compensation),,2 Chief Executive Officer
7,AAFT Workday Management,CONDITION_RULE-6-999,And,in the selection list,Value specified in this filter,Management Level (Compensation),,1 Board of Directors
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for looking into it .
<xsl:number level="any"/> generates partially correct results for me .
What it actually does is it generates a sequence for the first inner for-loop for example Sl.no: 1, 2,3,4, ....so on till 330 and the second inner for loop generates another sequence starting from for example Sl.no: 1,2,3... so on till 103.

My requirement is to generate sl.no starting from1,2,3,4 so on till 433(330 which first for-loop generate and 103 which second for-loop would generate). Sl.no - sequentially should be added into text file as and when I write rows into the textfile.

Comment: I'm  new here , If I'm not very clear then please let me know.

Comment: @SasukeSurendra - The hard part with answering this question is that if we copy your input XML and your XSLT and run them ourselves, we can't reproduce what you're seeing. For example, your only `xsl:template` matches `Report_Data_Outer` which doesn't exist in your input. If we change that to `/` we start to get decent output, but since there is no `Filter_Boolean` in your input, we can't reproduce the sequence numbers that you're seeing.

Comment: @SasukeSurendra - I updated my answer with a modified `xsl:number` and an example, but I'm still only guessing.

Comment: Thank You @Daniel Haley Much appreciated.. That was exactly a piece of code I was looking out for.

Thanks to you!